# Mutually exclusive regular expressions

Tags: regex, mutual-exclusion

If I have a list of regular expressions, is there an easy way to determine that no two of them will both return a match for the same string?

That is, the list is valid if and only if for all strings a maximum of one item in the list will match the entire string.

It seems like this will be very hard (maybe impossible?) to prove definitively, but I can't seem to find any work on the subject.

The reason I ask is that I am working on a tokenizer that accepts regexes, and I would like to ensure only one token at a time can match the head of the input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you detect if two regular expressions overlap in the strings they can match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849447/how-can-you-detect-if-two-regular-expressions-overlap-in-the-strings-they-can-mat)

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. You mean that two given regular expressions must be fully mutually exclusive to *any* input string? I.e., that of 2^32 of possible four-byte strings, a regex may only match one possibility? Isn't that the same as saying: match this exact string?

Comment: I mean the intersection of the regexes must be zero. No string matches more than 1 regex.

Comment: Furthermore I should note that I am talking about valid c# regular expressions.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid that my original answer still holds (and the last paragraph of Jim's answer). You cannot do that, simply because of the very nature of these C# (which are NFA) regular expressions. (PS: i deleted mine, as it was too crappy. Go for Jim's)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're working with pure regular expressions (no backreferences or other features that cause them to recognize context-free or more complicated languages), what you ask is possible.
What you can do is convert each regex to a DFA, then (since regular languages are closed under intersection) combine them into a DFA that recognizes
the intersection of the two languages.  If that DFA has a path from the start state to an accepting state, that string is accepted by both input regexen.

The problem with this is that the first step of the usual regex->DFA algorithm is to
convert the regex to a NFA, then convert the NFA to a DFA.  But that last step can
result in an exponential blowup in the number of DFA states, so this will only be
feasible for very simple regular expressions.

If you are working with extended regex syntax, all bets are off: context-free languages
are not closed under intersection, so this method won't work.

Comment: Intriguing thought. I think you're effectively crossing swords with Jeffrey Friedl, who said (page 157) "Talking about DFA matching is very boring". You just made it interesting again (accept that DFA still limits you highly)!

Comment: Thats what I feared. Very interesting answer though.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wkipedia article on regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Deciding_equivalence_of_regular_expressions) does state

*It is possible to write an algorithm  which for two given regular expressions decides whether the described languages are essentially equal, reduces each expression to a minimal deterministic finite state machine, and determines whether they are isomorphic  (equivalent).*

but gives no further hints.

Of course the easy way you are after is to run a lot of tests -- but we all know the shortcomings of testing as a method of proof.

Comment: I believe CaptnCraig wants to know if the languages have a non-empty intersection, not whether they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by only looking at the regular expression.

Consider the case where you have `[0-9]` and `[0-9]+`. They are obviously different expressions, but when applied to the string "1", they both produce the same result. When applied to string "11" they produce different results.

The point is that a regular expression isn't enough information. The result depends both on the regex and the target string.

Comment: *"When applied to string "11" they produce different results. "* actually: they don't, they produce the same result. Unless you add anchoring.

Comment: For pure regular expressions, what CaptnCraig asks is possible (but may be inefficient).  He wants to know if two regular languages (specified by regular expressions) have a non-empty intersection. For your example the answer is "yes".

Comment: @Abel: I think what he meant is that the part of the string they match is different. They'll both match though.

Comment: Sorry, my question was bad. Maybe what I meant to ask is that only one matches at position 0.

Comment: @Jim: how do you find that it is possible to find the intersection of two infinite sets? Can you elaborate? @Matti: indeed, they match different parts (unless you have a non-greedy engine, but that's rare, but it happens) :)

Comment: @CaptnCraig: perhaps you can update your q. with examples? Is "position 0" the same as the first character? Or the first string?

Comment: @Abel: Convert each regex to a DFA, combine the DFAs to produce a DFA recognizing the intersection, then check if the intersection is empty.  Regular languages are closed under intersection, and this can be proved in finite time even if the languages are infinite.

Comment: I was under the impression that the regexes were allowed to overlap, but that given the input strings, they were only allowed to match one of them, and only one of them. While you prove (non)intersection, intersection might be allowed if the rule is based on the input strings. I.e., `k*` and `j*` are good if input is `cat, khaki, joe`, while the regexps do intersect.